# Understanding of web services; SOAP, REST, JSON, XML

Tags: json, web-services, rest, soap

Whenever i look for a job advertisement they expect this "Familiarity with web services" or "Understanding of web services" thing.

So what exactly they expect from us?
Do they want us being able to use existing web service APIs in our applications  or being able to know how to develop a web service from scratch?

I am really confused because developing a web service from scratch should be a difficult task especially if you are not working in a company and a student like me. May be its because i haven't needed to develop a web service so far. I just use webservices in my application to show users some information. So i will be appreciated if someone explain this companies expectations i told u above..

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually in a professional environment when looking for somebody with some knowledge on webservices, what they need is somebody that have actual experience in the company custom web services, more than experience in public web service APIs available the internet. 
this means, that they need somebody that could  develop an application that uses any kind of webservice, with more or less any kind of specification or protocol,  or maybe writing or modifying an existing one, or at least has been involved in that kind of development, so he can be familiar with whatever that the staff developing the server can come up with. 
Note that companies can have a sort of processes in which they communicate with third party applications as client, or have to serve data to them. 
So, probably if you have made some websites that uses for example Facebook or Twitter APIs, that will be good for you as far as you have really been involved and know exactly what you are doing (and not just reading a reference an using it). Any experience is good, but note that almost anybody with some programing skills, have sometime used some public APIs, so that wont be the difference between two applicants, so if the dont mention some especific API they spect you to know, for sure they are expecting some deeper experience, so you can read a complex WS manual and implement a client which can comunicate with that WS, or even develop a custom service.

in any case you should be familiar with sockets, http request, JSON, HTML, SOAP protocol (in this case, also WSDL), parsing inputs and building well formatted outputs, etc (in php this is easy, but it is very different in C++, Java, etc)

As the good part for you, I can say that developing a web service is not so difficult, it is more or less an application that reads from database as you use to do, and instead of printing hmtl, prints xml or json.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time they are expecting individuals who have the ability and experience in writing applications that consume Webservices like SOAP, REST etc. if they want you to develop web services they will specifically mention that in the advertisement like "Experienced in web service development JSP,ASP.net" etc

Comment: But generally they are not clear about that. Thats why i asked. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 2):

I think starting from basic is very important. So what are these basics? I will try to explain a litle bit.

1. Learn http requests, how to parametirize a request, how to handle this request.
2. JSON and XML parsing, and see why web services uses these types as response(actucally in soap request and response are in xml format)
3. why there is a need for soap service method while there is rest service method, because rest is more easier to deal with.
4. I don't know which language you are better in, but there are a lot of frameworks in java, php, c# etc to deal with web services. I think you should start to learn a simple one for starting.

Comment: Thank you @ismail. You are right. Writing my own simple web service is good idea to understand how it works. I am good at Java and PHP btw. But i have no idea about how to develop a web service and open it to other developers usage. Can you give me an example in practice usage of webservices?

Comment: there is slim framework in php it's very simple to use. http://www.slimframework.com/

Comment: It seems that it is realy easy to use. And they have good documentation. Thanks again

Comment: What i'd recommend, instead of performing random tests, is that you think about a system that is actually useful, this is how you will get really involved, you will find actual problems, and you will find yourself taking a look at a wide sort of diferent aspects of a webservice. For example if you are good at java and php, you can create a mysql database, or use an existing one, and create a php webservice to access that database. Then, you create a java application, that uses that webservice to read data from the database. This is pretty much a what a real webservice is meant to, in practice

Comment: you are right carlos, I assumed mrgenco did't have a problem with provding data to publish in webservice, and ofcourse there have to be a db